# Opening Excel documents as soon as they are created using POI in Android

Tags: java, android

I've made a document using POI and its name is"Budget.xls". It gets saved in the Android folder of my phone. specifically Android/data/com.playmaker.BudgetOh/files/. But i want it to open as soon as it is created. But it doesnt seem to be working. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
saveExcelFile(this,"Budget.xls");// This is a method that creates the file

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/Budget.xls/");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "Budget.xls");

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);



            try {
                startActivity(intent);
                //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Application Available to View Excel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

this is my code for the saveExcelFile()

```
private boolean saveExcelFile(Context context, String fileName) {

    // check if available and not read only
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage not available or read only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    boolean success = false;

    //New Workbook
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    Cell c = null;

    //Cell style for header row
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
    cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    //New Sheet
    Sheet sheet1 = null;
    sheet1 = wb.createSheet("myOrder");

    // Generate column headings
    Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);
    //Row row2 = sheet1.createRow(1);


    c = row.createCell(0);
    c.setCellValue("Expense Title");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);


    c = row.createCell(1);
    c.setCellValue("Expense Amount");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);



    c = row.createCell(2);
    c.setCellValue("Categories");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    c = row.createCell(3);
    c.setCellValue("Date");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    c = row.createCell(4);
    c.setCellValue("Time");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    c = row.createCell(5);
    c.setCellValue("Location");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);



        String title;
        int counter=0;
    allExpenses = expenseManager.getAllExpenses();
    for (Expense expense : allExpenses) {
        allTitles.add(expense.getTitle());
        counter++;
    }
    Row  row2 = sheet1.createRow(1);
    int k=1;

    for ( int i=0; i < counter; i++) {
        title=allTitles.get(i);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        expense = expenseManager.getExpense(title);

        int j = 0;
            c = row2.createCell(j);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getTitle());
           // c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row2.createCell(j+1);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getAmount());
            //c.setCellStyle(cs);

            c = row2.createCell(j+2);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getCategory());
           // c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row2.createCell(j+3);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getDate());
            //c.setCellStyle(cs);

            c = row2.createCell(j+4);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getTime());
            //c.setCellStyle(cs);

            c = row2.createCell(j+5);
            c.setCellValue(expense.getComment());
           // c.setCellStyle(cs);

        row2 = sheet1.createRow(k++);


    }

    sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
    sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));

    // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(os);
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Writing file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error writing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error writing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != os)
                os.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "Budget.xls");
```

`Budget.xls` is not a valid [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type). Use `application/vnd.ms-excel` for the MIME type for Excel spreadsheets.

Also, replace:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/Budget.xls/");
```

with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Budget.xls"));
```

Partly, this gets rid of the invalid trailing `/`. Partly, this adds the `file` scheme that your approach lacks.

Comment: I get a toast saying. "This document cannot be opened".  But when i traverse the Android folder on my phone's internal storage I can open it manually. Thank you

Comment: Getting the same toast that the document cannot be opened

Comment: @Fritz_Playmaker: "It gets saved in the Android folder of my phone. specifically Android/data/com.playmaker.BudgetOh/files/" -- that is not the `Uri` that you are putting in your `Intent`. You need to write the file to the same place that you ask the other app to open. You might wish to have `saveExcelFile()` return the `File` object that you then use with `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: Please how do I do that. Please help me with some code

Comment: ive added my code for the saveExcelFile() method. Thank you

Comment: @Fritz_Playmaker: Instead of returning a `boolean` that you are ignoring, return a `File` (specifically, return `file`). You will notice that `new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);` is not the same as `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Budget.xls")` or `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Budget.xls/"`. **Only create the `File` object *once***, and use that in both locations, so you do not wind up with inconsistent values.

Comment: Please help with some code. Tried but getting errors

Comment: It's working now. I added the method .getAbsolutepath to the .getExternalStorageDirectory () method.

Comment: And I used the original full path